# Javascript age calculation on IPad

Tags: javascript, ipad

On every regular browser, the date is calculated normally .. like 38 year old.

On IPad I get a Not a Number (NaN) error... but why?

```
function getAge(date) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(date);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;

}
```

EDIT: NaN @ IPad, IE8 and correct working at Firefox&Chrome

Comment: What is the format of the input parameter `date`?

Comment: the input parameter is "1950-06-19"; read via jquery out of an xml-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following transformations on the input date string for it work properly on iPad/iPhone.

```
function getAge(date) {
    date = date.replace(/-/,"/").replace(/-/,"/"); //substitute - with /
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(date);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```

Comment: the input parameter is "1950-06-19" what lines do I have to delete? actually your method has no change

Comment: You need not delete. Try this `date = date.replace(/-/,"/").replace(/-/,"/");` It should work.

Comment: Why do you do the .replace twice?  you can just do a global replace:

    `date = date.replace(/-/g, "/");`

Comment: @bluesmoon This is intentionally done for replacing the first two occurrences of `-`. Doing `date = date.replace(/-/g, "/");` will replace all occurrences of `-` which is not intended.

Comment: @NarendraYadala but there are only 2 occurrences.  The string would not be a valid date if it had more than two dashes in it.