# This script gives me NaN in iPad

Tags: javascript

This code is supposed to give me the number of seconds until Mar 20th, 2014. It works fine on my computer, but it does not work on my iPad.
It gives me NaN in both safari and chrome.
What could be wrong?

```
function timer() {
    var day = "20";
    var month = "03"; 
    var year = "2014";
    var hour = "00"; 
    var minute = "00"; 
    var second = "00";

    var ToDate = new Date(month+ ","+day+","+year+" "+hour+":"+minute+":"+second);
    var now = Date.now();
    var NewDate = ToDate - now;

    var SecCount = Math.round(NewDate / 1000);
    document.write(SecCount);
    setTimeout(timer,1000);
}
```

this question is kinda the same in here: [Javascript age calculation on IPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711812/javascript-age-calculation-on-ipad), but I'm not sure how to implement the code

```
date = date.replace(/-/,"/").replace(/-/,"/"); //substitute - with /
```

into my code.
Thanks

P.S. This is the website's link: http://ss-cal.com/lab

Comment: Your copy / paste here has curly quotes instead of straight ones: `var day = "20”`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7712063/2763709 this answer is already given.. just perform according to that

Comment: @ jorg, just fixed that, and the code still does not work on iPad.

Comment: It's not a bad question... iOs' `Date()` handles date strings differently which is what the `date.replace` line is meant to fix. You don't need it because you already have everything as seperate vars. I'm thinking Mathias answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `var ToDate = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);` to create the Date object?

It is another way of creating a Date object without having to parse the value from a string and since you already have them separated it might even be quicker.

**Do note that it starts counting months from 0 = january and 3 = april instead of march**

See this fiddle for a few alternatives: http://jsfiddle.net/52XH2/2/

```
// ISO standard format
var ToDate = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "T" + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second);
var now = Date.now();
console.log(ToDate.toString());
var NewDate = ToDate - now;
```

See this for reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date